# reflecting materiliazed view in sqlalchemy2.0 using postgres as backend with async engine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

According to this github issue mat views and views are fully supported.

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/8085

However binding an engine to reflect method for an async engine is not yet implemented.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/errors.html#no-inspection-available
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6121
[image]

I have an async engine with fastapi that starts as such, `main.py`:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app_: FastAPI):
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.reflect(views=True),only=['eos_general'])
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    yield
```

My `models.py` is:

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

eos_general = Table("eos_general",Base.metadata)
```

And my `db.py` is:

```
engine = create_async_engine(CON_,echo=True)

SessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(engine)
```

If I use the above code I get this error:

`TypeError: reflect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bind'`

If I bind the engine :

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app_: FastAPI):
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.reflect(views=True,bind=engine),only=['eos_general'])
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    yield
```

I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: Inspection on an AsyncEngine is currently not supported. Please obtain a connection then use ``conn.run_sync`` to pass a callable where it's possible to call ``inspect`` on the passed connection. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd3s)
```

If I don't call `reflect` method as in `await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.reflect,only=['eos_general'])` then my views are not reflected and I cannot access it. So clearly I need to call the reflect method with `views` argument and without `bind`, but that is not possible. How can I solve this dilemma ?